# My tts app is not working in real android device

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am now moving on with a tts app in android. It is just an app for reading sms from my inbox. The app works smoothly in emulator and when comes to the real device, it receives the message but no speech is produced. Should I download and install the engine in my device too? I don't think so. If anyone knows the answer please suggest.

Comment: Do you get any exceptions when running the app on the phone? Attach a debugger and see what happens. Or try downloading the engine and see if that helps.

Comment: There is no exception in it. It receives the messages also. But it is not speaking out the messages. So should I download the engine again and install into my app?

Answer (score -1):

Connect your device with USB cable, go to Settings -> Applications -> Development -> Enable debugging, use debugger and put logs to check your application then you will get the errors.

Comment: No error is showing in that app. It is still receiving the messages and displaying it as usual. But my aim is to read the sms with the tts engine.